# Как поправить баг письма на маленьких экранах?

Tags: html, css

стили в инлайн вставляю
тут для удобства оставила

на маленьких экранах (пропадает **отступ справа** и
**картинки близко стоят**, тоесть левая не уменьшается)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html lang="uk">
    <head>
         <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <title>Письмо 1</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <!--[if !mso]><!-->
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <!--<![endif]-->
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
        <meta name="format-detection" content="address=no">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <style>
            body {
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
                width: 100%;
                overflow-x: hidden;
                -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
            }

            table {
                border-collapse: collapse;
                border-spacing: 0;
            }

            .block {
                display: block;
                padding-left: 20px;
                padding-right: 20px;
                margin-top: 0px;
                margin-bottom: 0px;
                margin-left: auto;
                margin-right: auto;
            }

            .block__item {
                border-bottom: 1px solid #e7e7e7;
                padding-top: 20px;
                padding-bottom: 20px;
            }

            .block__image,
            .block__pic {
                display: block;
            }


            .block__desc {
                font-size: 16px;
                line-height: 1.5;
                color: #363636;
                padding-top: 20px;
            }

            .block__box {
                display: block;
                white-space: pre-line;
                font-size: 10px;
                line-height: 1.5;
                padding-bottom: 20px;
                font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>

    <table class="block">
        
        <tr>
            <td class="block__item">
                <img class="block__image" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/fa/Mobile_black_160X160.png" alt="logo">
             </td>
            <td class="block__item">
                <img class="block__pic" src="https://i.ibb.co/JsMTqHS/roche.png" alt="roche">
            </td>
        </tr>
 
        <tr class="block__decor">
            <td class="block__desc">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Omnis repellat voluptates molestias quibusdam tenetur accusantium reiciendis soluta odit quidem ipsam suscipit cupiditate vero adipisci labore rem, maiores inventore maxime excepturi!

                <span class="block__box">(&copy;) 2</span>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: img.block__pic {
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-right: 20px;
}

Comment: @Arcadiy, все-равно справа будет не 20  . в   .block

Comment: Кэш почистите и проверьте снова

Comment: **Вариант 1:** можете уменьшить размер левой картинки, для экранов `@media (max-width: 767px)`, чтобы правая нормально влезла. **Вариант 2:** тегу `<tr>`, в котором два `<td>` с картинками, добавьте какой-нибудь класс для уникальности, и этому классу, для экранов `@media (max-width: 767px)`, присвойте свойства `{display: flex; flex-direction: column; align-items: center; border-bottom: 1px solid #e7e7e7;}`, только не забудьте у Ваших убрать `.block__item{border-bottom: none;}`

Comment: Для первого тега `<tr>` с картинками добавить свойства
`display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap; justify-content: space-between;`

Comment: @Arcadiy, не влезает картинка

Comment: @VOLK,так ведь нельзя использовать медиазапросы при табличной верстке. Та и флекс вроде тоже

Comment: а вы весь css пишите внутри таблицы то есть inline методом

Comment: @olena, почему нельзя?